# How to exclude images from the facebook like button

Tags: html, image, facebook, facebook-like

I'm having a problem with my facebook like button and the webpage. The webpage contains banners and random images as well as the article image, now facebook have removed the share button, though it still works, but with the current like button. Facebook chooses the image automatically, and sometimes it chooses the banners instead of the article image. Is there any alternate way instead of adding properties to the article images? Like exculding all the images but the article image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer isn't necessarily helpful for "excluding" specific images, but you can control what Facebook scrapes off of your page via [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) protocol with meta tags.  For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/redirect/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/logo.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="I'm on Facebook!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Hello World!" />
```

This will force Facebook to reference http://www.mysite.com/logo.jpg to use as thumbnail.

Additionally, my blog post on the related subject matter might help you:  http://weblogs.asp.net/kon/archive/2011/06/07/trick-facebook-scrapping-of-facebook-tab-url.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Kon has a good suggestion, but I'd rather have Facebook use the article image and not the logo, so what I did is put all logos and ad banners as `background-image` through CSS.

Something like this:

```
<a href="AD LINK HERE" title="AD TITLE HERE"><span style="background-image: url('IMAGE OF AD'); width:Xpx; height:Xpx; display:block;"></span></a>
```